# Jquery Styling for Autocomplete

Tags: jquery

This is driving me nuts!!! I'm using the JQuery Autocomplete UI 8.1 and everything works fine except for my styling on the autocomplete dropdown list hovering. I've narrowed it down to  the following line in jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.css. It seems that I can not add font-weight:bold to the line and get results. Can someone verify this? The CSS line is as follows:

```
.ui-state-hover, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-hover, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-hover, .ui-state-focus, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-focus, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-focus
{
    background: #394b6f url(images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_0_394b6f_1x100.png) 50% 50% repeat-x;
    color: #d9d9d9;
    font-size:1.1em;
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that this rule works, but adding the property `font-weight : bold` has no effect?

Comment: Have you tried `font-weight: bold !important;`? There can be a rule with more specificity that's preventing your style from taking effect.

Comment: @harpo That's exactly correct, I can change the color just fine though.

Comment: @ Ates font-weight: bold !important; fixed it. Thanks, make it the answer!

Comment: Wow, really good post here. @Ates - you should add your comment as the answer and it should be marked as 'correct'. I had the *exact* same issue. Why in the world it would not accept the 'font-weight: bold;' styling property, but 'font-weight: bold !important;' *does* indeed work. I understand the !important attribute, but it seems like a unnecessary hack to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `font-weight: bold !important;`? There can be a rule with more specificity that's preventing your style from taking effect.